# In Delphi 10.4 how do I provide the client tcp port to a WebBroker (TWebModule) when connecting via a TWebBroswer?

Tags: delphi

Maybe I'm not searching for the correct terms, or maybe this is not something that people usually care about but I simply cannot find out how to get the TCP Port the Client is connecting from.

I have a client that uses a TWebBrowser and an Apache server that has a Delphi WebModule running. The client connects to the URL on port 80 and somewhere in this I need to report on the port that client is using.

At the WebModule end I can collect the IP address of the incoming connection (Request.RemoteAddr) and any variables it sends in a POST body, but I cannot seem to get the port it is originating from.

I have found some explanation of this using Indy but nothing that has helped me to implement something useful at either the client or server end. I'm not sure where to go from here so any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Why do you need that information?

Comment: For HMRC VAT MTD they require the client port for their fraud prevention headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, `TWebRequest` simply does not expose the client's port, or access to the underlying request/socket needed so you can obtain the client's port manually.

This is a limitation of WebBroker itself, not of Indy (which is one of the available backends that WebBroker can use, via Indy's `IdHTTPWebBrowserBridge` unit. Indy has access to the client port, but you don't have access to the Indy HTTP server that WebBrowker uses internally).

Comment: Both the client and the server are running on Windows, do you know if I can get this information from Windows within Delphi?

Comment: There are APIs for iterating TCP connections, namely `Get(Extended)TcpTable/2()`. But only the underlying socket behind the WebRequest knows the exact connection being used. **IF** the client has a unique IP (ie, there are not multiple clients connected to server from behind the same router/proxy) then you can iterate the table looking for the tuple of server IP/Port and client IP to find the client port.  But if the client IP is not unique then all bets are off.

Comment: Thank you Remy. The only open connections to this IP from the client will be the application I am working with so I do plan to get the table and find the open connection. I just can't see any other way of doing this right now.